# Showing $\lim\limits_{R \uparrow \infty} \frac{1}{R^3} \int_{-R}^R \psi^2 (w,x) \, dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space.

Let $\psi:\Omega\times\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ such that

- $\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(w,x)\, dx = 0 ,\, \forall \omega \in \Omega$
- $\psi'$, the derivative of $\psi$ w.r.t $x$, is a stationary process
- $E[\psi'(\omega, x)] = 0 ,\, \forall x \in \mathbb R$
- $Var[\psi'(\omega, x)] < \infty  ,\, \forall x \in \mathbb R$

Then almost surely, $$\lim\limits_{R \uparrow \infty} \frac{1}{R^3} \int_{-R}^R \psi^2 (w,x) \, dx = 0$$

Comment: Can you get the variance of $\psi (w,x)$?  If the variance is bounded, then the answer is obvious, since the expression is $\frac{2}{R^2}$ times the average (over x) of the variance.

Comment: We have no information about the variance of $\psi$